# Массовое добавление строк в базу

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

Хочу добавить большое количество данных в БД. Когда список `items` маленький все работает хорошо. Но как только я задаю большой список у меня выдаёт ошибку

```
except -> (<class 'pymysql.err.OperationalError'>, OperationalError(2014, 'Command Out of Sync'), <traceback object at 0x7feac8cfac88>)
except -> (<class 'struct.error'>, error('unpack_from requires a buffer of at least 8 bytes',), <traceback object at 0x7feac8cfe7c8>)
except -> (<class 'pymysql.err.InternalError'>, InternalError('Packet sequence number wrong - got 4 expected 1',), <traceback object at 0x7feac8cfe648>)
```

Сам код

```
def addUsersBulk(Admin, items):
    try:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        db = []
        for item in items:
            db.append((Admin, item))
        sql = 'Insert INTO userdata(AdminId, Username) VALUES (%s, %s)'
        cursor.executemany(sql,db)
        pdb.set_trace()
            connection.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print("except -> " + str(sys.exc_info()))
        x=3
    finally:
        x =2
```

База данных `MariaDB`

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что у вас один `connection.commit` на все `cursor.execute`?

Comment: @strawdog всё верно

Comment: @strawdog исправил чуток этот метод. Я пишу телеграм бота. Мб соединение не успевает отключаться или как?

Comment: а у вас что, мультитред?